# mouse drag & drop

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

how to implement mouse drag&drop process
example 
SetCursorPos(32, 32);
mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.RIGHTDOWN,0,0 ,0,0); 
mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.RIGHTUP,0,0 ,0,0); 
SetCursorPos(38, 38);
mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN,0,0 ,0,0);
mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP,0,0 ,0,0);

this is code for open whatever in topleft of the screen 
 how to implement the drag & drop in this particular code or anyotherways?

Answer (score 1):

Here is Microsoft's Drag and Drop Overview

Forms .NET 1.1:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973845.aspx

Forms .NET 2.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0(VS.80).aspx

WPF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would have to look into the Drag and Drop event(s) of the form, I think you need to enable OnEnter on the form aswell, its been a while since i've done windows forms programming.

Think it is called DragEnter, you can read more on the following pages:

http://vicky4147.wordpress.com/2007/02/04/a-simple-drag-drop-in-winforms/

[c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/DoingDragandDropUsingCSharp11302005020610AM/DoingDragandDropUsingCSharp.aspx)

Other than that i'd look into [uzbones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581491/mouse-drag-drop/581511#581511) answer