# How to Make a Mouse Scroll Programmatically?

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation

**Related question:** [mouse drag & drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581491/mouse-drag-drop) (identical code snippet)

---

how do I a make mouse scroll programmatically?
I've tried:

```
SetCursorPos(32, 32);
 mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.RIGHTDOWN,0,0,0,0);
 mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.RIGHTUP,0,0 ,0,0); 
 SetCursorPos(38, 38);
 mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN,0,0 ,0,0);          
 mouse_event((uint)MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP,0,0 ,0,0);
```

The above code-snippet opens the top-left most item in a screen.

Does anyone have a code-snippet that will made the mouse scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to scroll to a specific place or just scroll in general?

If you are trying to scroll to a specific place, like the end of a text box, you could do something like the code code:

```
myTxtBox.SelectionStart = myTxtBox.TextLength;
myTxtBox.ScrollToCaret();
```